# An exercise for c + linux

Tags: c, linux, string

"In this task, you need to create a shared dynamic library libsolution.so which implement a function with the following prototype:

```
int stringStat (const char * string, size_t multiplier, int * count);
```

The function returns the length of string value is multiplied by the multiplier, and increases in the value of 1, which indicates to count."

My code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

unsigned strln(const char *str)
{
    unsigned int len = 0;

    while(*str!='\0')
    {
          str++;
          len++;
    }

    return len;
}

int stringStat(const char *string, int multiplier, int *count)
{ 
    *count = *count+1;
    return strln(string)*multiplier;
}

int main(void) { 
    printf("%d", stringStat("hello", 2, 2));
    return 0;
}
```

Errors with lines 18-21:

> parallels@debian-gnu-linux-8:~/labs/lab1$ gcc -o solution solution.c -c
>   solution.c: In function ‘main’:
>   solution.c:19:38: warning: passing argument 3 of ‘stringStat’ makes pointer from integer without a cast
>     printf("%d", stringStat("hello", 2, 2));
>                                         ^
>   solution.c:12:5: note: expected ‘int *’ but argument is of type ‘int’
>    int stringStat(const char *string, int multiplier, int *count){

Errors without lines 18-21:

I compiled with the -c option, its working, but for some reason when you try to start ./solution it report "Permission denied", corrected the chmod, now here:

> parallels @ debian-gnu-linux-8: ~ / labs / lab1 $ ./solution bash:
>   ./solution: can not execute binary file: Exec format error

I have read a lot of information here, i understand that problem with pointers and declaring, but i dont know what to do next.
Its a little hard for, give me some examples in your answers, plz.

Comment: You are passing `2` (a value) to `int *count` of `stringStat` function......it is plain wrong. You should start study something about pionters

Comment: You used `-c`, so gcc is going to generate an object file instead of an executable.

Comment: Side note: `strln` return an `unsigned` int while `stringStat` return an int.

Comment: Please compile with `-Wall -Wextra -Wpointer-arith`

Comment: `printf("%d", stringStat("hello", 2, 2));` should be `int two=2; printf("%d", stringStat("hello", 2, &two));`

Comment: `gcc -o solution solution.c -c solution.c` is compiling solution.c to an object file that would normally be called solution.o but the -o changes the name to solution - it is not an executable file.  Remove the -c to compile solution.c into an executable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would expect the return value for `stringStat()` to be `size_t`. But, as you say that the task requires adherence to the function prototype:

```
int stringStat (const char * string, size_t multiplier, int * count);
```

That is what we will use. It is worth noting that the Standard Library function `strlen()` has a return type of `size_t`, which is an `unsigned` integer type guaranteed to be able to hold any array index (and hence appropriate for this use). I would also want to change `len` and `count` to `size_t` and `size_t *`, but we will leave these as `int` and `int *` to match the function prototype.

Now, the spec that you provided says of the `stringStat()` function that:

> The function returns the length of string value is multiplied by the multiplier, and increases in the value of 1, which indicates to count.

I interpret this to mean that the return value of the function is the length of a *string* that is `multiplier` times as long as the input string. I originally thought that the value to be stored at the address `count` should be the size of the *character array* which is to hold such a string, that is, the multiplied length of the string plus space for the `\0` terminator. This does not quite make sense, but keeping a counter of the number of times that `stringStat()` is called does not make much sense either, so I will defer to your code which appears to be keeping a counter in the latter sense.

Putting this all together, the `strln()` function looks fine, except that in other circumstances I would recommend using `size_t` instead of `int` here. The `stringStat()` function looks fine. I changed the code in `main()` to make more clear what is happening with the different variables. In particular, you were passing the integer constant `2` as the third argument to `stringStat()`, which led to the original error. You need to pass a pointer to an `int` here. So I declared the `int` variable `main_counter`, initializing it to zero. The address of `main_counter` is a pointer to `int`, and is passed to the function. Inside the `stringStat()` function the value stored at the address held by `count` (the value stored in `main_counter`) is incremented, before returning the multiplied string length. Each time `stringStat()` is called, the value in `main_counter` will be incremented.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int strln(const char *str)
{
    int len = 0;

    while(*str != '\0') {
        str++;
        len++;
    }
    return len;
}

int stringStat(const char *string, int multiplier, int *count)
{
    int new_len = multiplier * strln(string);

    *count = *count + 1;
    return new_len;
}

int main(void)
{
    int main_counter = 0;
    char *str = "hello";
    size_t mult = 2;
    int newstr_len = stringStat(str, mult, &main_counter);

    printf("Original string: %s  ---  length: %d\n",
           str, strln(str));
    printf("String length multiplied by %zu\n", mult);
    printf("New string length: %d\n", newstr_len);
    printf("Times stringStat() called: %d\n", main_counter);

    return 0;
}
```

Program output:

```
Original string: hello  ---  length: 5
String length multiplied by 2
New string length: 10
Times stringStat() called: 1
```

Answer (score 1):

You are passing 2 as the pointer. 2 is an integer and not a pointer to the integer.

Put this :

```
int k = 2;
stringStat("hello", 2, &k);
```

In the above code, `k` is an integer which equals to `2` and `&k` is the address of the variable `k` and so in `stringStat` function, the count pointer starts pointing to `k`.

Comment: David, could you wright righ variant?
I need to review code to catch it.